# Wordpress Functions.php Advice

Tags: php, wordpress

I am looking to take away some hyperlinks from the functions.php folder on my wordpress website.

I do not want any of the below to be clickable, only the text show. Is this possible to do?

```
} elseif ( is_tag() ) {
        echo "<li typeof='v:Breadcrumb'>" . single_tag_title( '', false ) . '</li>';
    } elseif ( is_day() ) {
        echo __( "Archive", 'thrive' ) . ": ";
        the_time( 'F jS, Y' );
        echo '</li>';
    } elseif ( is_month() ) {
        echo __( "Archive", 'thrive' ) . ": ";
        the_time( 'F, Y' );
        echo '</li>';
    } elseif ( is_year() ) {
        echo __( "Archive", 'thrive' ) . ": ";
        the_time( 'Y' );
        echo '</li>';
    } elseif ( is_author() ) {
        echo __( "Author's archive", 'thrive' ) . ": ";
        echo '</li>';
    } elseif ( isset( $_GET['paged'] ) && ! empty( $_GET['paged'] ) ) {
        echo __( "Archive", 'thrive' ) . ": ";
        echo '';
    } elseif ( is_search() ) {
        echo __( "Search results", 'thrive' ) . ": ";
    } elseif ( is_archive() ) {
        echo __( "Archive", 'thrive' ) . ": ";
    }
```

I appreciate any tips!

Many thanks!

Comment: I dont use wordpress so  I can only say you can add into li tag:
`onClick="return false;"`

Comment: You can use CSS live li a { pointer-events: none; }

Comment: No links will be generated by the code in the snippet that you've shared. They're getting added from somewhere else. Can you add more of the surrounding code before and after these statements?